# Regex to capture text not beginning with number but containing number

Tags: regex, perl

I am writing a perl script and part of it is to capture data that does not begin with a number. I have tried `(\w)\s+(\d+)\s+(\S+)\s+(\d.+)`. Below are some parts of the file(too big to put all lines here).

The text I want to capture is

```
BBACCap            8            N/A           48,46,44,42,40,38,36,34,32,
```

or can be

```
IG-XL_DataTool     N/A          N/A           N/A
```

or

```
DC-30              1            N/A           1,0
```

The regex does match for the above data I need however I am also capturing data(which I don't want) such as

```
1       2
2       3, 4
```

and also(which I don't want)

```
1.0     BBAC-15     805-004-50 0301B5C5 0829-E 5445
    aka: 805-004-02,805-004-03
```

but only `E 5445
        aka: 805-004-02,805-004-03` from the above.

Any help on this?

Comment: Something [like this](https://regex101.com/r/bD6vT8/1)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to be sure what you need, but it looks like you can split each line on whitespace and select just the first three fields, rejecting any line whose first field starts with a decimal digit

Here's a demonstration which reads from files specified on the command line

```
while ( <> ) {
    my @fields = split;
    next if $fields[0] =~ /^[0-9]/;

    print "@fields[0..2]\n";
}
```

Comment: More succinctly, `while(<>) { my @fields = split; print "@fields\n" if $fields[0] !~ /^\d/; }`

Comment: Or then even `perl -Ane 'print if $F[0] !~ /^\d/' file`

Comment: @DavidHammen: There are problems with that alternative. Firstly, the real code is unlikely to have just a single statement to be executed for filtered-in file records, so the statement modifier form of `if` can't be used unless we also enclose the statements in a `do` block, and that's very untidy. Secondly, the `\d` character class includes many non-ASCII Unicode characters as well as just the decimal digits, so `[0-9]` is safer unless you use `\d` with the `/a` *ASCII-safe* regex modifier which requires version 5.14 or later of Perl

Comment: @tripleee: As I mentioned, the `print` is just my own imagining, and the OP is very likely to want multiple statements executed for each matching line. Also, only the first three fields are of interest, so printing the whole line won't do what is required. Perhaps `say "@F[0..2]"` is acceptable

Comment: I have tried the solution @stribizhev suggested in the question's comments. It some how doesn't write the last(third) parameter(the one with csv) into the file. It gives a `Use of uninitialized value $_ in concatenation` at some line number that doesn't exist(300+ when I only have 149 lines). Here's my [current code](http://rextester.com/APM23933) in case if you would like to view it. Not sure whether it's not capturing or a logical error in it. EDIT: I changed the link, see the last line if you want to see one of the lines that was written to the file.

Comment: I'm not really good with `next` or `last`, so I'm still figuring out with my current codes or if not I'll try out your answer. In the codes I am trying to read from a specific line to another line but I don't really know how so I just break if it reaches my desired end line.